# Remove 'Switch to plain text editor' in CKEdtior

Tags: theming, wysiwyg

Where do I disable the switch to plain text editor link from the CKEditor. I checked the settings and I don't find anything that support this.

I tried to disable it with display:none; through CSS but it wont respond to it. Here is the code

```
<a id="switch_edit-body-und-0-value" class="ckeditor_links" onclick="javascript:Drupal.ckeditorToggle(['edit-body-und-0-value','edit-body-und-0-summary'],'Switch to plain text editor','Switch to rich text editor');" href="javascript:void(0);" style="">Switch to plain text editor</a>
```

I both tried with the id tag and the class to disable it but it dosen't work.

```
.ckeditor_links a {
display: none;
}
```

does not work :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which module are you using to add CK Editor? I'm using WYSIWYG and there's an option for this. It's under the settings for a text format (e.g. /admin/config/content/wysiwyg/profile/full_html/edit) there's a vertical tab at the bottom of the page called Basic Settings, inside of that the option is called "Show enable/disable rich text toggle link"

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use CSS. There is an option within the CKEditor profile.

Go to Configuration > Content Authoring > CKEditor then select edit next to the profile you want to effect. This way you can also limit this too certain users.

Then select editor appearance and scroll down to "Show the disable/enable rich text editor toggle" then select hide and save the profile.

Answer (score 0):

It is a hardcoded style. A quick solution is the frowned upon use of !important. This will work.

a.ckeditor_links{
        display: none !important;
    }

Answer (score -2):

You can do it programmatically.

Include this code into the hook_form_alter function of your module:

```
drupal_add_js(
  'jQuery().ready(
    function() {
      jQuery(".ckeditor_links").hide();
    }
  );',
  'inline'
);
```

Greetings